# ITfoxtec IDX13102: Exception thrown while reading 'AuthnContext' for Saml2SecurityToken

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I'm getting the following exception while trying to read the SAML assertion using ITfoxtec Identity SAML2 MVC Core package v4.10.7 in an ASP.NET core 3.1 application:

**IDX13102: Exception thrown while reading 'AuthnContext' for Saml2SecurityToken. IDX10000: The parameter 'value' cannot be a 'null' or an empty object. (Parameter 'value')**

The error occurs while trying to read the SAML response (3rd line below) in ACS:

```
var binding = new Saml2PostBinding();
var saml2AuthnResponse = new Saml2AuthnResponse(config);
binding.ReadSamlResponse(Request.ToGenericHttpRequest(), saml2AuthnResponse);
```

I tried using the SAML Tracer for Chrome and the SAML response appears to be coming OK there even as I saw the 500 Internal Server error.

I'm not sure what value is null in AuthContext. Here's my AuthContext from the SAML tracer:

```
<saml2:AuthnStatement
    xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
                              AuthnInstant="2024-01-05T20:20:08.069Z"
                              SessionIndex="REDACTED"
                              >
    <saml2:AuthnContext>
        <saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>
    </saml2:AuthnContext>
</saml2:AuthnStatement>
```

I tried playing around with the Saml2 config, but can't make it work. Currently, my Saml2 config looks like this:

```
"Saml2": {
    "IdPMetadata": "https://dish.okta.com/app/REDACTED/sso/saml/metadata",
    "Issuer": "http://www.okta.com/REDACTED",
    "SignatureAlgorithm": "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256",
    "CertificateValidationMode": "ChainTrust",
    "RevocationMode": "NoCheck",    
    "SigningCertificateFile": "okta.cer"
  }
```

I'm stuck. Please help!